OpenAI Assistant API - read from file and return response
I created an Assistant in the OpenAI interface, set it up with Retrieval and uploaded a .txt file. When I ask the Assistant in the interface, it responds correctly from the uploaded file.
I would like to have a WPF app to connect to the Assistant I created earlier and using the uploaded file.
I connect to the created Assistant with the code below:
try
{
    var requestData = new
    {
        assistant_id = assistantId
    };

    var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new 
    AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OPENAI_API_KEY);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v1");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads", null);
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JObject result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);

    return result["id"].ToString();
    }
catch (Exception ex)

There's nothing wrong with that, I manage to access Assistant and it returns the threadId.
I am asking the Assistant with the following code:
    var messageData = new
    {
       role = "user",
       content = questionText
    };

     var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OPENAI_API_KEY);
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v1");
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageData),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.openai.com/v1/threads", null);
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JObject result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);

    var runData = new
    {
      assistant_id = assistantId
    };

     content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(runData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     response = await _httpClient.PostAsync($"https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{threadId}/runs",content);
     responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     result = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);

     return result["id"].ToString();

And I get the result back with the following code:
 var _httpClient = new HttpClient();
 _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", OPENAI_API_KEY);
 _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OpenAI-Beta", "assistants=v1");
 _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/{threadId}/messages");
 var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
 Root? result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responseContent);

 return result.data[^1].content[^1].text.value; 

Here is an extract from the answer:
  "id": "msg_6OgK2DOxWI8uyAjJoHpCP1Qg",
  "object": "thread.message",
  "created_at": 1713269774,
  "assistant_id": "asst_xxx",
  "thread_id": "thread_5owDiegJh0XQerkQrLVVZnFd",
  "run_id": "run_FLiEWzUNQIM3YbJKUL6zT69Y",
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": {
        "value": "The uploaded file contains a listing of...",
        "annotations": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "file_ids": [],
  "metadata": {}

No matter what question I ask the Assistant, it seems to answer with a default text about what data is in the uploaded file.
I can't ask specifically for a particular item from the uploaded file, or if I ask it again and again, I still get the same text with the same content, slightly paraphrased.
Annotations does not contain anything either time, only the text property has a value.
But, when I ask what the uploaded file name is, it returns it correctly.
If I then ask for a specific item in the uploaded file, I get a response like this again:
The document you uploaded seems like a .... dataset. Here are some things I could help you with:

Why is the communication not continuous, like on the interface, if I continue the conversation via the same threadId? Also, why can't it read from the uploaded file?
Maybe I should create the Assistant itself in code, upload the file and use it, instead of creating it in the OpenAI portal and just connecting to it? But I don't understand why the latter doesn't work that way, if I can connect to it and see the uploaded file in Assistant.
Thanks a lot for your help!
